# Form has the wrong action when created by an ajax partial - Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a form that gets loaded by an ajax partial. When it gets swapped in, the form that loads on that ajax partial is targeting the wrong controller/url. I attempted to target the correct controller in a variety of ways, but it was always over-written to the same, incorrect controller/url.

Additionally, the form loads correctly if it is loaded on page refresh - only when it is loaded by ajax does it target the incorrect controller.

Here is what the form html looks like when it loads incorrectly:

```html
<form class="new_prediction" id="new_prediction" action="/predictions" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
```

Here is what the form html should look like, and what it does look like after page refresh:

```html
<form class="new_predictionend" id="new_predictionend" action="/predictionends" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
```

My question is, why does the form target an incorrect controller "/predictions" when the form is loaded by ajax? The partial clearly shows that a new "Predictionend" model is the object for the form, and so should be targeting "/predictionends" like it does correctly when the page is refreshed.

Here is the form partial that loads for both the page refresh and the ajax load:

```
<%= form_for(Predictionend.new, remote:true) do |f| %>
  <div class="sidebar-open-close-comment-div">
   <%= f.text_area :comment, placeholder: "Make a closing comment", class: "close-comment-textarea" %>
  </div> 

  <div class="sidebar-close-button">
    <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: "btn" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the ajax file that loads the form:

```js
$('.stockpage-sidebar-prediction').first().html("<%= j render partial: 'predictions/prediction_end', locals: {prediction: @prediction} %>");
```

Controller that loads the ajax:

```html
class PredictionsController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @prediction = @user.predictions.build(prediction)
    @prediction.save
                                                   
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js { 
        if invalid_start
         render 'shared/_error_messages.js.erb'
        else 
          render "predictions/create.js.erb"
        end
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```html
  post    'predictions'                  =>   'predictions#create'
  get     'predictions/:id'              =>   'predictions#show'
  get     'predictions/hover/:id'        =>   'predictions#hover'


  post    'predictionends'               =>   'predictionends#create'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have two options here , please find below.

= form_for @model, :url => predictions_url, :remote => true do |f|

OR

= form_tag(predictions_url, :method => "post", :id => "model_form", :remote => true) do |f|

Comment: Thanks for the response. While it seems like both of those should work, neither do. The form is still loaded with the wrong controller action "/predictions" even though I specify that the url should be url: predictionends_url